# How can i install Percona's pt-archiver for XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp, percona

I need to archive my MySQL-database every year and I found the [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/index.html). But I want to try it on XAMPP first and not on the actual server. I used the Shell from the XAMPP Control Panel.

First, I installed pt-archiver with the command:

```
wget percona.com/get/pt-archiver --no-check-certificate
```

The installation was successful. I tried my first dry run:

```
pt-archiver --source h=127.0.0.1,D=db_ilb,t=erstbegegnung --file 'C:\xampp\Archive\%Y-%m-%d-%D.%t' --where "1=1" --limit 1000 --commit-each --dry-run
```

and it threw an error:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Attempt to reload DBD/mysql.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.

 at ./pt-archiver line 2499.
```

After trying to install DBD::mysql via CSPAN, another error was thrown:

```
Warning: No success on command[C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.39)
  MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz
  C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'DBD::mysql'.
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

I don't know what to do next... If you have any other suggestions for archiving, let me know :)

Comment: Not [officially supported on Windows](https://www.percona.com/services/support/mysql-support/percona-toolkit-supported-platforms-and-versions), you _may_ be able to get it to work, with a helluvalot of fiddling. You are better of just creating a small Linux VM (or perhaps a [Docker](https://github.com/fr3nd/docker-percona-toolkit)) if you want to play around with it for testing.

Comment: @Wrikken Thank you I'll give it a try!